# Retrieve deployment timestamp of Maven artifact programmatically?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

does anyone know whether (and how) it is possible to retrieve the deployment timestamp of a Maven artifact from the repository programmatically?

I need to write a plugin that checks the project's dependencies and their dependencies as well. The plugin must check the deployment timestamps of the dependencies and their dependencies to ensure version compatibility during the release process of a very large legacy application with strong coupling between its modules. => Just for the background ;)

So I've tried several Maven APIs (maven-core, maven-artifact, ...) but even the Metadata interfaces don't have something like a timestamp feature.

Comment: Are you running the build job from Jenkins ?

Comment: no, also local. But I found out that this approach wouldn't hit my problem and I switched it to another approach that just compares parent versions, analyzes dependencies and dependency management, ... Thanks so far!

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: I would if I could but it is too complex to explain here. We've already discussed about it for about 3 days now, ...