# Does Maven or its metadata have a way to get the artifact publish timestamps?

Tags: maven, gradle, plugins, repository, artifact

Working on a maven/gradle plugin to get this timestamp in a report programatically. The goal is to find how old some of these jars are, when were the latest ones published, etc.,.

The only alternate working ways are:

1. use a maven central search API "http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:" + id.group + "+AND+a:" + id.name + "+AND+v:" + id.version + "&wt=json"
2. HTML parsing a public maven utility page like https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/latest.

These are not the standard ways to access this.

Probably related question: [Retrieve deployment timestamp of Maven artifact programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063135/retrieve-deployment-timestamp-of-maven-artifact-programmatically)

[image]